# Android studio add different size drawable and layout folder

Tags: android, android-studio

how can i add those folders in my project in android studio

```
res/drawable-ldpi/
res/drawable-ldpi-v8/
res/drawable-ldpi-v11/
res/drawable-mdpi/
res/drawable-mdpi-v8/
res/drawable-mdpi-v11/
res/drawable-hdpi/
res/drawable-hdpi-v8/
res/drawable-hdpi-v11/
res/drawable-xhdpi/
res/drawable-xhdpi-v8/
res/drawable-xhdpi-v11/
res/drawable-xxhdpi/
res/drawable-xxhdpi-v8/
res/drawable-xxhdpi-v11/
res/layout-land
res/layout-small-port-v4
res/layout-sw600dp-v13
res/layout-w480dp-v13
res/layout-v11
res/layout-port
```

i just made new project and i cant see any folder of those in my project

this is image of my project folders

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you have to create new folder inside res folder

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio, right click on the `app` module and select New in the popup menu. (Alternatively, push Alt-Ctrl-Insert on Windows or Alt-Cmd-Insert on OS X.) Then select Android Resource Directory. Use the dialog box to select the modifiers you wish to use.

Note that since these are folders, you can always use Windows Explorer to add them manually. Similarly, you can switch the Project View in Android Studio to the Project View instead of the default Android View by clicking on the drop down menu at the top of the Project Window:

[image]

Now the Project Window contains the exact directory hierarchy of your project. You can modify this hierarchy similarly to how you would in Windows Explorer.